# Python looping assignment

Tags: python-3.x

We just started learning about loops and one of my tasks is to

```
def multiples(n,xs):
```

Given   an  integer n and   a   list    of  integers    xs, check   and return  values  from
xs that are multiples   of  n as    a   list,   preserving the  occurrence  order from  xs.

Restriction:   Do  NOT modify  the incoming    list    xs: build   up  a   new list    to  return.

```
Examples:

 multiples(2,[1,2,3,4,5,6]) → [2,4,6]

 multiples(5,[5,10,5,10]) → [5,10,5,10] #keep   duplicates

 multiples(3,[11,13]) → []
```

Could anyone help on how to start/solve out this problem?

Comment: I suggest taking a few minutes to review the Help Center, starting with [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below function -

```
def multiples(n,xs):
    return filter(lambda x: not x%n, xs)

>>> multiples(2,[1,2,3,4,5,6])
[2, 4, 6]
>>> multiples(5,[5,10,5,10])
[5, 10, 5, 10]
>>> multiples(3,[11,13])
[]
```

## From doc

filter(function, iterable) - Construct a list from those elements of iterable for which function returns true.

Comment: Alternatively, a list comprehension: [x for x in xs if x % n == 0]

Comment: @rikkigibson yes,  thats a nice way to achieve same